# NavigationController push animation from top to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation, pushviewcontroller

As the title says, i'm trying to make a push animation, with the next viewcontroller coming in from the top. The thing is, i've tried using every solution on stackoverflow and google. Here's the problems i've encountered:

With CATransitions im getting a buggyflow, with a black transition, and especially in the right top corners it's looking really buggy..

Tried using  where i get the same problem, a black transition.

Tried using custom segue, again black transition.

Tried using [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view... this works better, but I can't get the same push animation, I can only chose flip animation, resolve animation and so on.

Sorry for bad english, not my main language. Hope you understand what I mean and know how to solve this problem.